# sony camera alphs 6000 actTakePicture changes from available to unavailable

Tags: sony

I'm using sony api to remotely controll alpha 6000 to take pictures. However,actTakePicture was really erratic during testing, changing from available to unavailable sometimes. How should I handle this error?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the actTakePicture action is not in the proper state to take a picture or it is finishing up taking a picture. Before calling this function you should use getEvent to be sure that the camera is not idle. It is also possible that you need to make the "startRecMode" call before calling actTakePicture. Here is the special note from the documentation about this:

> **Special note (details)**
>
> This API instructs the server side to shoot still image. When this API
>   is called and the server starts shooting still image, the camera
>   status will change as follows. The camera status can be obtained by
>   "getEvent".
>
> Camera status: "IDLE" -> "StillCapturing" -> "StillSaving" -> "IDLE"
>
> Note that this sequence is the example of typical case.
>
> The client should check the "getEvent" parameter ("cameraStatus") and
>   check if it is "IDLE" before calling this API. The camera needs to
>   prepare for the next shot, therefore it may take time to start next
>   capturing after changing to "IDLE". The camera will start capturing as
>   soon as possible.
>
> In case of long exposure, the server will return "40403" error ("Still
>   Capturing Not Finished") within several tens of seconds. If status
>   code "40403" is received, capturing is not completed. Use the
>   "awaitTakePicture" API to receive status on capture. If status code
>   "40403" is received for "awaitTakePicture" again, the client can call
>   "awaitTakePicture" until the capture is done.
>
> This API is only available when the shoot mode is "still".
>
> Some camera models need "startRecMode" API call before capturing still
>   image. See "startRecMode" for details.